# Bootstrap navigation menu not collapsed by default in mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a Drupal 8 website theme with Bootstrap 3.0. I am very new to web programming, and I haven't been able to figure out how to make the navbar collapsed by defualt.

Any help would be appreciated!

```html
<!-- Header and Navbar -->
<header class="main-header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        {% if page.header %}
          {{ page.header }}
        {% endif %}
      </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="navbar-header col-md-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navigation">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button> 

          {% if page.primary_menu %}
            {{ page.primary_menu }}
          {% endif %}
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!--End Header & Navbar -->
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser console?

Comment: No errors or warnings